# Backbone.js - Filtering collection from search results

Tags: backbone.js, collections, filter

I'm using browser localStorage to prototype a concept with Backbone.JS. Hoping to understand its structure better and build out models, collections and what REST services should include. The scenario I'm having difficulty with is filtering the collection (based on a form textbox) before displaying a table of results that match.

**From my collection:**

```
 initialize: function(){
    this._meta = {};

    this.meta("sortOrder", "asc");
    this.meta("sortColumn", "trackNumber");

    //this.fetch();
    console.log("TrackCollection - Initialize: Collection has " +  this.length + " items");
    if(this.length == 0) { 
        console.log("Generating new items into collection");

        var trackItem1 = new TrackModel();
        this.add(trackItem1);
        this.add(trackItem1);
        this.add(trackItem1);
        this.add(trackItem1);
        this.add(trackItem1);

    }

}


searchLocalStorage: function(trackItems) { 
    console.log("TrackCollection - searchLocalStorage: Collection has " +  this.length + " items before filter");

    if (trackItems == "") { 
        console.log("No Search terms provided");
        return this;
    }

    var searchTerms = trackItems.split(', ');

    console.log("Search Terms: " + _.isArray(searchTerms) + " / " + searchTerms.length + " / " + JSON.stringify(searchTerms));

    var filteredCollection = [];

    _(this.filter(function(data) {
        if( _.contains(searchTerms, data.get("trackNumber")) ) {
            console.log('Matched ' + data.get("trackNumber"));
            console.log(data);
            filteredCollection += data;
        }
    }));

    console.log(filteredCollection);
    this.reset(filteredCollection); 

    console.log("TrackCollection - searchLocalStorage: Now Collection has " +  this.length + " items");

},
```

**From my search view**

```
 var TrackSearchView = Backbone.View.extend({
el: $("#page"),

events: {
    'click #buttonTrackSearch': 'searchSubmit'
},

render: function(){
  $('.menu li').removeClass('active');
  $('.menu li a[href="'+window.location.hash+'"]').parent().addClass('active');
  this.$el.html(trackSearchTemplate);

  // add the sidebar 
  var sidebarView = new SidebarView();
  sidebarView.render();
},

searchSubmit: function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    console.log("View - TrackSearchView - searchSubmit");

    var searchData = $("#search").val();

    //this.collection.meta("searchData", searchData);

    this.collection = this.collection.searchLocalStorage(searchData);

    Backbone.history.navigate('summary', true); 
},
```

**From my list view:**

```
 var TrackSummaryView = Backbone.View.extend({
el: $("#page"),

events: {
    'click #summaryTrackItems thead th a': 'sortItemsByColumn'
},

render: function(){
  $('.menu li').removeClass('active');
  $('.menu li a[href="'+window.location.hash+'"]').parent().addClass('active');

  this.$el.html(trackSummaryTemplate);

  console.log("trackSummaryView - Collection has " + this.collection.length + " entries");
  this.collection.forEach(this.setupSummaryTableRow, this);

},

setupSummaryTableRow: function(trackItem) {
    var trackSummaryRowView = new TrackSummaryRowView({ model: trackItem, collection: this.collection});

    $(this.el).find("#summaryTrackItems").append(trackSummaryRowView.render().$el);
    return this;
},
```

**From my router:**

```
 var initialize = function(){

var app_router = new AppRouter;

var trackCollection = new TrackCollection();

app_router.on('route:trackSearch', function(){

    var trackSearchView = new TrackSearchView({ collection: trackCollection });
    trackSearchView.render();

});


app_router.on('route:trackSummary', function(){

    var trackSummaryView = new TrackSummaryView({ collection: trackCollection});
    trackSummaryView.render();

});

Backbone.history.start();
 };
```

Comment: What is the specific question here?

Comment: The log statements within searchLocalStorage of collection show that right results are being identified when performing a search. However the output displays a single instance of my default model.



As a question...Why does searchLocalStorage not return a filtered collection result to TrackSummaryView but a single copy of default model?